# un-struct in big query

Tags: database, data-structures, google-bigquery

I have a table with some struct data types that I can access but would like it as columns.

```
select 
  consignment id, 
  user 
from tbl
```

**What I currently have**

[image]

```
select 
  consignment id
  , user.name
  , user.email
  , user.externalId 
from tbl
```

**What I want**

[image]

I was able to get it by just calling every key of `user` but on a table with hundreds of columns that would be terrible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below

```
select 
  consignment id, 
  user.* 
from tbl
```

Comment: Wow, really obvious, thanks. Is there a way to concat column names so that I get "user_name" instead of "name"?

Comment: no. no easy way. theoretically this potentially can be achieved via manipulation with struct like unpivot it and then pivot, etc. but this does not look like reasonable practically